# How to Filter products by supplier in Purchase order?

Tags: odoo

I want to filter products list on Purchase Order by supplier. I added domain on product_id field, but it doesn't work.

```
 <field name="product_id" on_change="onchange_product_id(parent.pricelist_id,product_id,0,product_uom,parent.partner_id, parent.date_order,parent.fiscal_position,date_planned,name,price_unit,context)" domain="[('seller_ids','=',parent.partner_id)]" />
```

Comment: this domain will work why you get this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your domain is ok, just there one mistake you did.

you have to use domian like this way:

```
<field name="product_id" on_change="onchange_product_id(parent.pricelist_id,product_id,0,False,parent.partner_id, parent.date_order,parent.fiscal_position,date_planned,name,price_unit,context)" domain="[('seller_ids.name','=',parent.partner_id)]"/>
```

Regards,

Comment: Earlier it worked for me.  Now it is throwing error like: `Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture! `.  Not sure what is happening...

Comment: Fixed it now.  Actual problem is I have `widget="selection"` on the same element.  This filter and selection widget will not fit on same element.  Now no issues for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this domain, domain="[('seller_ids.name','=',parent.partner_id)]"
```